# Any recommendations to enforce use of keybindings rather than equivalent command mode commands?

Tags: command-line, vim-windows, habit-breaking

Context: I learned about the `:[v]split` command long before I learned the shortcuts `Ctrl-w+[s|v]` and as a result I find myself typing these commands often. Is there a way to break this habit ? (as a similar example, when I was first learning vim I mapped the arrow keys to `nop` to force me to use `hjkl`.

The catch is I'd like `:[v]split <...>` to still work.

Generically, do you have any recommendations to force the use of keybindings rather than the equivalent command mode commands ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try to add this code in your `vimrc`:

```
let g:my_overlooked_commands = [
                            \   { 'old': 'vsplit', 'new': 'C-w v' },
                            \   { 'old': 'split',  'new': 'C-w s' },
                            \   { 'old': 'q!',     'new': 'ZQ' },
                            \   { 'old': 'x',      'new': 'ZZ' },
                            \]

fu! s:alternative_reminder(cmd) abort
    call timer_start(0, {->
    \ execute('echohl WarningMsg | echo "['.a:cmd.'] was equivalent" | echohl NONE', '') })
    return ''
endfu

fu! s:remember(list) abort
    for cmd in a:list
        let old = cmd.old
        let sold = string(old)
        exe printf('
        \            cnorea <expr> %s getcmdtype() ==# ":" && getcmdline() ==# %s
        \?                   %s.<sid>alternative_reminder(%s)
        \:                   %s
        \',          old, sold, sold, string(cmd.new), sold
        \         )
    endfor
endfu

call s:remember(g:my_overlooked_commands)
```

To use it, inside the list `g:my_overlooked_commands`, you would need to add the old commands you're currently using, and their new counterparts you would like to use, but frequently forget to.

After executing an old command, a message should be displayed in the command-line to remind you that there's an alternative.

---

Edit: Concerning these 2 [questions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13887/any-recommendations-to-enforce-use-of-keybindings-rather-than-equivalent-command/13891?noredirect=1#comment23861_13891):

> 1. How does the %s.alternative_reminder(%s) part work?

`printf()` expects a string as its first argument (called `{fmt}` by the help, probably as an abbreviation for `format`), and one or more expressions. The format (first argument) can contain one or several `%` items. There are several types of items, `%s` is one of them. The `s` stands for `s`tring. It means that you want `printf()` to replace it with the value of an expression whose type is a string. Here's an example:

```
:let var = 'string' | echo printf('here is a %s', var)
```

Going back to the code, the contents of the format is:

```
cnorea <expr> %s getcmdtype() ==# ":" && getcmdline() ==# %s
\?                   %s.<sid>alternative_reminder(%s)
\:                   %s
```

It contains 5 `%s` items. So, `printf()` expects 5 more arguments after the format. Here they are given on the next line:

```
old, sold, sold, string(cmd.new), sold
```

The values of these expressions will replace the items in the format, respecting the order in which they are passed to `printf()`.

So, this command:

```
exe printf('
\            cnorea <expr> %s getcmdtype() ==# ":" && getcmdline() ==# %s
\?                   %s.<sid>alternative_reminder(%s)
\:                   %s
\',          old, sold, sold, string(cmd.new), sold
\         )
```

Should be (untested) equivalent to something like this:

```
exe 'cnorea <expr> '.old.' getcmdtype() ==# ":" && getcmdline() ==# '.sold
\.              '?     '.sold.'.<sid>alternative_reminder('.string(cmd.new).')'
\.              ':     '.sold
```

You don't need to invoke the `printf()` function. But as soon as I get a concatenation of strings and other expressions, I find that using `printf()` makes the code a little more readable.

Once `printf()` has done its job, `:execute` should receive a string looking like this:

```
    cnorea <expr> vsplit getcmdtype() ==# ":" && getcmdline() ==# 'vsplit'
                  \?     'vsplit'.<sid>alternative_reminder('vsplit')
                  \:     'vsplit'
```

This is an abbreviation which expands the word `vsplit` into the value of an expression, which uses
the ternary operator `?:`. If the test:

```
getcmdtype() ==# ":" && getcmdline() ==# 'vsplit'
```

… is true, then, the value of the expression is:

```
'vsplit'.<sid>alternative_reminder('vsplit')
```

… otherwise:

```
'vsplit'
```

Note that `<sid>alternative_reminder('vsplit')` is an expression whose value is the one returned at the end of the function. By default, a function returns the number `0`. But here the function explicitly returns an empty string. So, the function doesn't add anything to the expansion of `vsplit`, because it's replaced with an empty string. However, to get to the returned value, Vim must process the code of the function. The latter contains some logic to trigger a warning message when necessary.

The goal of the test is to prevent the reminder to be triggered if you're not on a regular Ex command-line, or if you're not at the beginning of the command-line.

Basically, `vsplit` should always be expanded into `vsplit` (unchanged), but the reminder should be triggered when you execute the command at the beginning of a regular Ex command-line

---

> 2. Is it possible to adapt this to actually prevent the split from occurring? Removing the %s. from the quoted line above almost achieves
>      this, but it breaks the :vsplit  case.

I haven't tested it very long and I don't know how reliable it is, but you could try this code:

```
let g:my_overlooked_commands = [
                            \   { 'old': 'vsplit', 'new': 'C-w v' },
                            \   { 'old': 'split',  'new': 'C-w s' },
                            \   { 'old': 'q!',     'new': 'ZQ' },
                            \   { 'old': 'x',      'new': 'ZZ' },
                            \]

fu! s:alternative_reminder(old, new) abort
    if getcmdline()[-1:-1] ==# ' '
        call feedkeys("\<bs>".a:old.' ', 'int')
    else
        call timer_start(0, {->
        \ execute('echohl WarningMsg | echo "['.a:new.'] was equivalent" | echohl NONE', '') })
    endif
    return ''
endfu

fu! s:remember(list) abort
    for cmd in a:list
        let old = cmd.old
        let sold = string(old)
        exe printf('
        \            cnorea <expr> %s getcmdtype() ==# ":" && getcmdline() ==# %s
        \?                   timer_start(0, {-> execute("call <sid>alternative_reminder(%s, %s)") }) ? "" : ""
        \:                   %s
        \',          old, sold, sold, string(cmd.new), sold
        \         )
    endfor
endfu

call s:remember(g:my_overlooked_commands)
```

Comment: Nice! I have two questions about this: 1. How does the `%s.<sid>alternative_reminder(%s)` part work? 2. Is it possible to adapt this to actually prevent the split from occurring? Removing the `%s.` from the quoted line above almost achieves this, but it breaks the `:vsplit <file>` case.

Comment: Thanks for the long explanation. Unfortunately, I wasn't clear enough in how I asked my question. What I don't understand is how the expanded `'vsplit'.<sid>alternative_reminder('vsplit')` results in the desired behaviour. Typing `:vsplitfunction()` into the command-line doesn't work, so how does returning this as the result of an `<expr>` abbrev result in the desired functionality?

Comment: @Rich Ah sorry about that, I added some more explanation. But basically,  `<sid>alternative_reminder('vsplit')` is an expression whose value is the one returned at the end of the function. By default, a function returns the number `0`. But here the function returns an empty string. So, the function doesn't add anything to the expansion of `vsplit`. However, to get to the returned value (an empty string), Vim must process the code of the function. The latter contains some logic to trigger a warning message when necessary.

Comment: @Rich to better understand, try this command: `fu! Func() ^@ return 'world' ^@ endfu | echo 'hello '.Func()` But do not type `^@` literally, instead press `C-v` then `C-j`.

Comment: Oh duh. Of course the function is evaluated *before* the `<expr>` abbrev returns: it's an expression, not a string. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 3):

It's not an elegant solution, but the following might work for you:

```
cnoremap split<cr> echo "Use CTRL-W s!"<cr>
cnoremap vsplit<cr> echo "Use CTRL-W v!"<cr>
```

*N.B. You might need to adapt this with the exact series of keystrokes you use e.g. `:vs<cr>`*

This means that instead of splitting the window, the `:split` and `vsplit` commands will admonish you for not using the keyboard shortcuts.

`:vsplit <...>` will work as normal, though: as soon as you diverge from the mapping (e.g. by typing `<space>` after `:vsplit`), Vim will abandon it.

The downside is that *while* you are typing `vsplit` you will lose most of the visual feedback, because Vim is waiting to see whether or not you are typing the mapping or a different series of keystrokes with a matching prefix. This may or may not be an issue for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and taking the time. I upvoted your response but felt like @user852573 's response deserved to be the accepted one since it was more thorough.